# Finding a sequence of characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to identify messed up placeholders in my resx files.

For e.g., I am trying to identify the 3rd and 5th line in below sample:

> Déplacer le dossier local « {0} » vers « {1} »
> Déplacer le contenu serveur « {0} » vers « {1} »
> Déplacer le contenu local « {0} » vers « {1\ »
> Démarrer la synchronisation
> {Démarrer lors de la connexion 0}
> Démarrer {0} lors de la connexion

Update: Adding more examples of messed up placeholders that need matching:

> ملفّات محمّلة {0}
>
> نقل محتوى محلي "{0}"  إلى "{1}"
>
> إعادة تسمية المحتوى المحلي  "{0}" ك "{1}"
>
> إعادة تسمية المحتوى المحلي  "{0}" ك "{1}"

I came up with below regex but something is wrong:

```
/^(?=.*[\{\}9])(?!\{[0-9]\}).*$
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is match string that contains "{" or "}", but does not contain {0-9}.

please help.

Comment: Reading the description of your goal I don't see how the 3rd line would match

Comment: the third line contains`{0}`. That doesn't match your description

Comment: Try `{(?![0-9]})[^{}]*}?`.

Comment: I understand that 3rd line wouldn't match, but wasn't able to figure out how to write a nested condition.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for the regex. I tried matching it. It does seem to work for the given sample, but does not for my other text. e.g.:  حذف مجلد الخادم "{0}"

Comment: I guess a mere `{(?![0-9]})|(?<!{[0-9])}` should work for you. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to match any brace - opening and closing ones - if it is not before (or after) a brace counterpart and the 1-digit whole number.

You can use the following regex:

```
{(?![0-9]})|(?<!{[0-9])}
```

It will match 2 alternatives:

- `{(?![0-9]})` - a `{` that is **not followed** by a 1-digit number and a `}`
  or...
- `(?<!{[0-9])}` - a `}` that is **not preceded** by a `{` followed by a 1-digit number

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7B(%3F!%5B0-9%5D%7D)%7C(%3F%3C!%7B%5B0-9%5D)%7D&i=D%C3%A9placer%20le%20dossier%20local%20%C2%AB%20%7B0%7D%20%C2%BB%20vers%20%C2%AB%20%7B1%7D%20%C2%BB%0D%0AD%C3%A9placer%20le%20contenu%20serveur%20%C2%AB%20%7B0%7D%20%C2%BB%20vers%20%C2%AB%20%7B1%7D%20%C2%BB%0D%0AD%C3%A9placer%20le%20contenu%20local%20%C2%AB%20%7B0%7D%20%C2%BB%20vers%20%C2%AB%20%7B1%5C%20%C2%BB%0D%0AD%C3%A9marrer%20la%20synchronisation%0D%0A%7BD%C3%A9marrer%20lors%20de%20la%20connexion%200%7D%0D%0AD%C3%A9marrer%20%7B0%7D%20lors%20de%20la%20connexion%0D%0A%D9%85%D9%84%D9%81%D9%91%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%91%D9%84%D8%A9%20%7D%0D%0A%D9%86%D9%82%D9%84%20%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%89%20%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%8A%20%22%7B0%7D%22%20%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%89%20%22%7D%22%0D%0A%D8%A5%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9%20%D8%AA%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%89%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%8A%20%22%7B0%7D%22%20%D9%83%20%22%7D%22%0D%0A)

In C#, suffice is to use this regex in a `Regex.IsMatch(line, regex)` call.

Answer (score -1):

This will match all lines that do not contain `{0-9}` but contain at least one `{` or `}`:

```
^((?!{\d}).)+?((?=[{}]).)+?$
```

However, you say that you want to match lines 3 and 5 based on your condition. Line 3 contains `{0}` so it wouldn't match.

However, since you are using C#, I would do more of the processing in C# than in Regex (`strings.txt` contains your first French input):

```
var strings = File.ReadAllLines("strings.txt");

var r1 = new Regex("{[0-9]}");
var r2 = new Regex("[{}]");

var filtered = strings.Where(s => !r1.IsMatch(s)).Where(s => r2.IsMatch(s));

Console.WriteLine("\tinput:");
foreach (var s in strings) Console.WriteLine(s);

Console.WriteLine("\n\tresult:");
foreach (var s in filtered) Console.WriteLine(s);

Console.ReadLine();
```

However this doesn't match anything for your second, Arabic input, because all of them actually contain `{0-9}`.